# DateTime Conversion works for string value but for calculated value throws "out-of-range" error

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

So I keep getting an error and I have no clue what is prompting it. I have the SQL

```
STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(CAST(((ETADate * 10000) + ETATime) * 100 AS NVARCHAR),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' ')
```

Which produces on the problem line the value :

```
'20161102 00:50:00'
```

When I call the following SQL, the DateTime conversion works **just fine**.

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '20161102 00:50:00')
```

But when I try to put both together with the following:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(CAST(((ETADate * 10000) + ETATime) * 100 AS NVARCHAR),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '))
```

Then and **only then**, I get the error "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Does anyone here have any clue as to why the my nvarchar to datetime conversion **works** when I manually supply a string but **fails** when I try to convert from math that generates the **exact same string?** Any insight anyone has would be great because as of now this makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: can you add some sample data for the ETADate and ETATime values.

Comment: are your ETAdate and ETATime values bigints?

Comment: Bob, on the line that is throwing the error, ETADate is 20161102, and ETATime is 50.

Comment: pacreely, they are just ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to use date based functions to build your datetime.

```
Select
Dateadd(hh,11,
Dateadd(mi,50,
Dateadd(ss,30,
Convert(datetime,eatdate))))
```

Sorry if I've made any mistakes, I'm typing on my phone.

Comment: OP is not building time out of values, just adding the : and space.

Comment: Well, your method of converting my stupidly formatted dates and times into actual DateTimes seems to work. I still don't understand why the method I was using was having problems, but the way you've provided works without issue so I'll just use it instead. Thanks!!

Comment: I tried your method using int and it failed due to overflow, but it worked when I used bigint. The dangers of multiplying by 10000

Comment: Hi Bob, the problem is with converting the string to datetime. The string build is not the end goal.